# how to draw contours and create a bounding rectangle on an image, using android and openCV

Tags: android, opencv

How can I draw the contours and create a bounding rectangle on the image in android?

What i have so far,

```
    Mat imageMat = new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(photo, imageMat);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imageMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
       Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageMat, imageMat, 255,
           Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 7, 7);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(imageMat, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageMat.cols(), imageMat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(imageMat, resultBitmap);
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
```

[image: Binary image]

Comment: i meant to say ... how can we draw ....

Comment: have a look at `drawContours` and `boundingRect` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html) for the `DrawContours` method, and you can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30412592/opencv-drawcontours-in-java).

As for the bounding rectangle, have a look at the same documentation linked above, and (following [this example](http://answers.opencv.org/question/25755/drawing-bounding-box-in-java/)) have

```
List<Rect> boundingRects = new List<Rect>();
for (MatOfPoint points : contours){
    boundingRects.append(Imgproc.boundingRect(points));
}
```

Although I have not tested the code (I can't at the moment) this should solve your problems (examples are reasonable in my opinion and they're confirmed solutions for similar problems).

Let me know!

Comment: let me give it a go.

Comment: contour color is black and white even after changing, i dont know why?!

Comment: Where are you drawing it? Update the question with new code please

Comment: it would be really helpful if you showed me how to implement thisList<Rect> boundingRects = new List<Rect>();
for (MatOfPoint points : contours){
    boundingRects.append(Imgproc.boundingRect(points));
}

Comment: im drawing the contour around the rectangles in the image and later crop out the largest rectangle, which is the goal, of the project.